# Partial atomic charge from lodwin charge - quantum espresso

Tags: quantum-espresso, monte-carlo

Looking to calculate partial atomic charges for a GCMC calculation. I have relaxed a structure with QE. Projwfc.x gives Lodwin charge of a Ni(II) atom as;

```
 Atom #   1: total charge =  17.6172, s =  2.4126, p =  6.8500, d =  8.3546,
                 spin up      =   9.5784, s =  1.2145,
                 spin up      =   9.5784, p =  3.4344, pz=  1.1514, px=  1.1353, py=  1.1476,
                 spin up      =   9.5784, d =  4.9295, dz2=  0.9894, dxz=  0.9794, dyz=  0.9887, dx2-y2=  0.9864, dxy=  0.9856,
                 spin down    =   8.0388, s =  1.1981,
                 spin down    =   8.0388, p =  3.4157, pz=  1.1512, px=  1.1179, py=  1.1466,
                 spin down    =   8.0388, d =  3.4251, dz2=  0.7934, dxz=  0.7089, dyz=  0.5418, dx2-y2=  0.5462, dxy=  0.8347,
                 polarization =   1.5396, s =  0.0165, p =  0.0187, d =  1.5044,
```

How do I convert from Lodwin to partial atomic charge? (Removing just the valence electrons, leaves an unreasonably high charge)

Comment: +1 bit please carefully proofread this. Lowdin vs Lodwin, and Quantum ESPRESSO.